# How to get command line history in tkcon using the arrow keys?

Tags: tcl

In Tkcon the way to access command line history is through the menu and you cannot access it with the up/down arrow keys. For tclsh there are a few readline libraries that add these capabilities, but those do not work in Tkcon.

I am running an Arch Linux system and Tkcon is version 2.5.

Comment: Are you sure? Up/down arrow works for me on Tkcon. What version are you using?

Comment: Also, what OS/platform are you running on?

Comment: you can try readline too..

Comment: @slebetman. I ammend the question to include OS and tkcon version.

Comment: @Vishwadeep readline is not working. I used rlwrap too without success.

Comment: Which version of _Tk_ are you using? There were some changes in 8.6 that required an update to Tkcon to make it work again…

Comment: @DonalFellows: version is 8.6 - What update is required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATING TO VERSION 2.7 resolved the problem. For version 2.5 I found a patch [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/tkcon/bugs/48/).

Comment: The specific change that forced the update was that the built-in bindings were switched in Tk 8.6 to much more strongly use the virtual event system. That makes cross-platform portability easier for most apps, but broke apps that do extensive binding rewriting (i.e., Tkcon especially).